# Velocity + IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, velocity

I'm trying to get started with the Apache Velocity Template Engine. I'm using IntelliJ for my IDE.

Here's my simple code from the Velocity dev guide:

```
public class velocityMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", "~/IdeaProjects/velocity_sample/web");
        Velocity.init(props);

        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

        context.put("foo", "foobar");
        context.put("bar", "fooboo");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        Velocity.mergeTemplate("template.vm", context, writer);
        System.out.println(" template: " + writer);

        String string = "We're using $bar $foo to render this.";

        writer = new StringWriter();

        Velocity.evaluate(context, writer, "mystring", string);
        System.out.println(" string: " + writer);
     }
}
```

And here is my project view:

[image: project view]

Here is the template.vm content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Velocity Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    $foo
    $bar
</body>
</html>
```

When I'm deploying the application on Tomcat 8, the `template.vm` only shows the variables `$foo` and `$bar` as plain text. It seems that the code from `velocityMain` class doesn't even effect that page.

IntelliJ also says that the method `Vetocity.mergeTemplate()` is deprecated.

I'm very thankful if anybody can help me out with this.

Comment: I'm sorry but AFAIK, tomcat doesn't run any "main", you should clarify and tell us what you are doing / trying to do and how.

Comment: Solved it by myself with using the VelocityViewServlet. Thank you anyway! :)